# TabPanel focus issue

Tags: javascript, extjs, layout, tabs, extjs5

I've provided a link to the sencha fiddle of the example I have issues with. Basically when I have tabPanels as the element at the bottom of the window if I scroll down to them and try to click on any of its tabs, the whole scroll jumps to the top of the window. And by that makes the use of tabPanel almost impossible. I'm not sure if its the layouts or I am doing something else wrong.

here's the sencha fiddle link

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/uv9

Answer (score 2):

to make your example code work as expected I think that putting a fixed height to the tabpanel is enough.
Using this solution on your fiddler, it works. I hope that it is what you need on your real project.

```
... 
// panel holding the tabpanel
xtype: 'panel',
items: [{
     // tabpanel
     xtype: 'tabpanel',
     //plain: true,
     height: 300,
     items: [{
          title: 'P1',
          xtype: 'panel',
          height: 200

     }, {
          title: 'P2',
          xtype: 'panel',
          height: 200
      }, {
         title: 'P3',
         xtype: 'panel',
         height: 200
      }]
   }]
...
```

Comment: Thanks Mattex83, this is a solution, however, a temporary one. These tabs within the  tabpanel will have dynamic data presented. Therefore, the height of the tab is something that will not have a fixed height. Appreciate the effort.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Maybe, if you can, consider to modify your layout using an Accordion. I think it would give a better ux